# Avoid Braintree recurring-billing for a single subscription

Tags: braintree, billing, recurring-billing

I need to let users choose to block a monthly recurring-bill.
Default subscription options are:

```
never_expires: true,
number_of_billing_cycles: nil
```

Is

```
never_expires: false,
number_of_billing_cycles: 0
```

the proper update to a subscription to accomplish that? Is 0 allowed as value for number of billing cycles? I want to update the subscription for a single user so that is not paying on the following month

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

You should be able to accomplish your goal through creating a [discount](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/add-ons-discounts). You'll need to create a discount associated with a plan via the Control Panel. However, via the API you'll be able to add a discount to the subscription. Specifically, [you should create a discount on the subscription](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/create/ruby#discounts) that equals the amount of the subscription in order to bypass a month.

Answer (score 0):

Braintree doesn't really do this (at least, that I can tell...)

The way I would approach a 'free month' sort of thing is to simply do a refund for that month https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/manage/php#refunding-a-subscription

Comment: So i can't handle different recurring-bill for different users?

Comment: There are some options - https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/manage/php and 
https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/manage/php#see-also tell what you can do.  You need to know what you can work with to make your promises out to the customers.  It sounds like you want what I call a 'free month because X.....' sort of thing, which is more of a marketing thing than technical.  Braintree does payments, not marketing (from my experience) - so you have to find what features they allow and work with it - refunds are simple.....

Comment: Maybe i didn't asked my question in the proper way, but i just need to let a single user to uncheck a checkbox for automatic subscription renewal. From backend i call the Braintree update api to update a single user subscription to cancel it instead of renew it at the end of the month

Comment: That is VERY different!  'block a subscription' makes me think just one time, while 'cancel' is a normal operation... https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/cancel/php

Comment: Currently i can cancel the subscription, but instead of cancelling it i just want to stop the renewal at the end of the month without, let's say, call the cancel api 5 minutes before the renewal

Comment: I don't understand at all what you are saying..... - "stop the renewal at the end of the month" = CANCEL......  The subscription continues until the 'end of term' (which is typically a month) and does not renew - no matter what time the cancel is called (cancel can only be called on a settled transaction, i.e., 'current month' and then it just won't renew)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161725/discussion-between-cfp-support-and-razinar).